# App close and background to be black when i ask permission for read phone state at run time in marshmallow

Tags: android

the below code is work only in M version of android, i get issue when i request for permission, after permission request system dialog will be  open but its background to be black and after  when i try to accept/deny i found app was closed.

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

```
public boolean checkPermissionPhoneState(final String manifestPermissionRequestState, final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_PHONE_STATE) {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,manifestPermissionRequestState);
    if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(manifestPermissionRequestState)) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{manifestPermissionRequestState}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_PHONE_STATE);
            contactPermission = false;
        }else{
            requestPermissions(new String[]{manifestPermissionRequestState}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_PHONE_STATE);
            contactPermission = false;
        }

    } else {
        contactPermission = true;
    }
    return contactPermission;
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                contactPermission = true;
                Snackbar.make(view, "Permission Granted", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Permission Denied", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't just copy paste code here, what you have tried till now mentioned here. Members here are not to solve your application's bugs. Be specific while asking your questions.

Comment: please add the error stacktrace....

Comment: i am new on this so from this question  i remember to attach issue detail.

Comment: i am not getting any error in log

Comment: believe me, if your app crash you definetly will get an output. Remove your filter on the logcat window and set it to "No Filter". Then you will get every output from the whole device. Sometimes the error is not shown with the filter related to your app....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer, this app did not crash from background it will close automatically when dialog appear. the main issue was i include "android:noHistory='true'" in Android-manifest,when dialog appear app remove from stack. So after remove this tag from Manifest file my app work properly.